# Convert something to Jquery object

Tags: jquery

```
$('#tags option').each(function(index, item) {
    // var i = this;
    //if (jQuery.inArray(i.value, idArray)) {
    // i.attr('disabled', 'true');
    // }
    item.attr('disabled', 'true');
});
```

How to I convert the item parameter into Jquery object so I can use all the nicety's like .attr?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$(item).attr('disabled', 'true');` should work

See: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#elements

Answer (score 25):

You can just wrap it like this:

```
var jQueryItem = $(item);
```

where `item` is a DOM element.  In fact, you'll find yourself doing this a lot in callback functions, since usually `this` refers to a DOM element and you'll usually want to operate on that using jQuery API calls.

Comment: this actually answers the title of the question, which was great for me! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(item).attr("whatever")
```

Jquery takes many different types of arguments, including straight up HTML elements, [read the doco](http://docs.jquery.com/Core)